# Regex for integer in the word not failing properly

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create regex to exactly match one string format.
The strings will be like this

```
A3476,TextA
B5628,TextB
A9871,TextC
```

The first character should be either 'A' or 'B' and it will follow integer number which should be exactly 4 chars in length and followed by ','.
After comma only Three words will repeate those are either 'TextA' or 'TextB' or 'TextB'.

I have tried this regex

```
(A|B)(\d{4})(,)(TextA|TextB|TextC)
```

When I add any alphabet in the integer number or integer number is greater than 4 chars in length the string match should fail but it is not failing.

Suppose if the string is like this

```
A653k7876,TextA
```

I am getting result like this `7876,TextA`. The result is missing character 'A' and reading integer from end. My intention is it should fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is fine, except that you should indicate where it should start and end with the match. The `^` special character indicates the start of a line or string, and `$` the end. So, try this instead:

```
^(A|B)(\d{4})(,)(TextA|TextB|TextC)$
```

Make sure you specify [`RegexOptions.Multiline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) when creating the `Regex` object to make this work.

Comment: Thanks it solved. I was trying with Singleline option and without '^' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
\b(A|B)(\d{4}),(TextA|TextB|TextC)\b
```

\b denotes the word boundary

You might find this link useful: [C# Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we need more info, as if I use strings exactly as you provided they work fine:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@"A653k7876,TextA", @"(A|B)(\d{4})(,)(TextA|TextB|TextC)"));
```

outputs False - as you want.